# How to use @RegisterReflectionForBinding with nested types in Spring Boot 3?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, graalvm-native-image

I'm currently using `@RegisterReflectionForBinding({ A.class, B.class })` to tell GraalVM's native-image what classes I need to process with reflection.

But how do I use it for nested types?

**Note:** Using spring-native and Spring Boot 2.x, I could specify a nested type as a string using `@TypeHint(typeNames = "C$NestedType")`.

Comment: This can be handled by register required reflection in src/main/resources/META-INF/native-image/reflect-config.json, but it would be much more convenient to be able to declare it in the source code that require the reflection.

Answer (score 0):

If your nested class is visible, you should be able to use `@RegisterReflectionForBinding(C.NestedType.class)`.

If it is not, you have 2 options:

- You register each reflection entry with `RuntimeHints` API that allow to specify either `String` or `TypeReference` for non-visible classes. But you lose `@RegisterReflectionForBinding` "cleverness" on registering was is typically needed for serialization/binding.
- Otherwise you can implement and register your own `BeanFactoryInitializationAotProcessor` as documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/aot.html#aot.bean-factory-initialization-contributions) and leverage `ReflectiveRuntimeHintsRegistrar` to register your non visible classes with reflection to create the classes.

Notice that `@RegisterReflectionForBinding` can be used in the package of package-protected nested classes.